# How do I list all connected Salt Stack minions?

Tags: saltstack

Sometimes my saltmaster hangs for a while on `salt '*' test.ping` waiting for downed minions to reply. Is there a way so see a list of connected minions, regardless of whether they respond to `test.ping`?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The official answer:

```
salt-run manage.up
```

Also useful are:

```
salt-run manage.status

salt-run manage.down
```

Comment: "salt-run -d"  Gives a full list of all the modules you can run with salt-run, well worth a read

Comment: `salt-run manage.versions` is also quite useful (reports minions' running versions and compares them to the master's)

Comment: Note that salt-run `manage.up` and `manage.status` appears to do a `test.ping` under the hood. At least, when I ran `manage.up`, it showed on the minions logs as `test.ping`..... If you want to ensure it doesn't need to send anything, use `alived` or one of the other manage functions

Answer (score 13):

From the master type:

```
ls -1 /var/cache/salt/master/minions
```

or:

```
ls -1 /etc/salt/pki/master/minions
```

Entering a faulty salt query (ex. salt '*' -) will also return a list of all the minions each followed by a message stating that the command is not available.  You can grep/cut away the extraneous characters.  Neither of these options are particularly elegant and the later doesn't address the timeout but it works while I'm looking for an answer to a similar question; "How to list all associated minions via the saltstack python api?".

Comment: I think something must have changed /var/cache/salt/master/minions appears to be a non-existent location now, /etc/salt/pki/master/minions is still good to go.

Comment: @OlyDungey Maybe it is distribution dependent. What Linux distribution were you using at that time ?

Answer (score 10):

There are [few new commands](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.manage.html#salt.runners.manage.not_alived) that makes it much more easier,

`salt-run manage.alived` Print a list of all minions that are up according to Salt's presence detection (no commands will be sent to minions)

`salt-run manage.allowed` Print a list of all minions that are up according to Salt's presence detection (no commands will be sent to minions)

`salt-run manage.not_alived` Print a list of all minions that are NOT up according to Salt's presence detection (no commands will be sent)

`salt-run manage.not_allowed` Print a list of all minions that are NOT up according to Salt's presence detection (no commands will be sent)

`salt-run manage.not_joined` Print a list of all minions that are NOT up according to Salt's presence detection (no commands will be sent)

Answer (score 7):

"salt-key -L"  will list all minions that whose public keys you've accepted on your master.

Comment: Thanks, but this lists accepted minion keys, not connected minions.

Answer (score 6):

I think one can use the grains module to achieve this:

```
salt '*' grains.get id
```

Answer (score -6):

To make ping to all minions, try on salt master node:

```
salt '*' test.ping
```

Comment: Have you read the question? It specifically is about alternatives to your method because this doesn't work in some cases.